# Rendering canvas "sub-elements" in React

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to set up a canvas render system for some React components (they also can render in SVG, depending on their properties). I haven't settled on how best to do this, but the approach I'm currently taking is to have a `CanvasManager` component, combined with `canvasContents` methods on the child components that take a context and draw their intended contents. This is set up like so:

```
export default class CanvasManager extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.childElements = [];
    this.canvasRender = this.canvasRender.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(...args) {
    super.componentDidMount && super.componentDidMount(...args);
    this.canvasRender();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(...args) {
    super.componentDidMount && super.componentDidMount(...args);
    this.canvasRender();
  }

  canvasRender() {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    const { width, height } = this.props;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.childElements.forEach((child) => {
      child.canvasContents(ctx);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { width, height, positionStyle, children } = this.props;

    const canvasChildren = React.Children.map(
      children,
      (child) => {
        const props = extend({}, child.props, {
          ref: (el) => {
            if (el) { this.childElements.push(el); }
          },
        });
        return extend({}, child, { props });
      },
    );

    return (<div style={ positionStyle }>
      <canvas
        ref={ (canvas) => { this.canvas = canvas; } }
        height={ height }
        width={ width }
      />
      { canvasChildren }
    </div>);
  }
}
```

The idea here is that the `CanvasManager` will let me handle full redraws of the canvas as needed, so any time any of the children get new properties they can call `forceRender` on the `CanvasManager` and clear and redraw the entire canvas as desired.

However, the ref function on the children seems to never actually fire, and `this.childElements` is always an empty array. (For reasons I don't understand, it does sometimes fire with `el=null`, hence the `if` statement.) How can I get access to the `canvasContents` methods on my child elements in `canvasRender`?

(Alternatively, if there is a better and entirely different way of doing this, I'm very much open to ideas.)

Comment: I might be missing something but I feel like this approach is quite convoluted. Can't you just have a canvas component that receives an array of objects in the shape of `{ source. width, height, top, left}` as a prop, and in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` you just draw those items on the canvas. If you're not using redux you can just have a parent component that holds the canvas and the elements that have to be drawn, and passes those elements down to the canvas whenever the list of elements gets updated.

Comment: Ah. The problem I've run into there is that the sub-elements have animations which are (currently) being managed in component-local state, so when I do this, the local state transitions don't affect the canvas. It's likely I need to change this architecture entirely to make canvas work properly here.